# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean on line 9

Tags: php, pdo

I am kinda new to PDO and I was searching for other similar questions to mine and I still haven't found any specific answer.

```
<?php
    require 'header.php';
    require '../lib/dbconnect.php';

    $SID = isset($_POST['S_ID']) ? $_POST['S_ID'] : ""; 
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM student WHERE `S_ID` = :S_ID';
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute([':S_ID' => $S_ID]); <--- it indicates that this line (line 9) has somehow an error
    $student = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);   
?>
```

EDIT: Sorry, Im kind of new here hehe.
I'm quite not sure what the error is but it just tells me that my execute function has failed. Might be my query is incorrect? I'd just like to confirm if the code i've written is correct? Many thanks!!!

Comment: Your prepare failed. Check for [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) to find out why.

Comment: Please include a question, rather than just the code dump.

Comment: The code as written is correct, though the answer is below is correct in that `$SID` is not the same as `$S_ID`, but your code isn't getting that far. What does the PDO error say when you check for it? Make sure to check for the exact error message, not just that it failed.

Comment: Ohh sorry for not being clear. I've already corrected the $SID to $S_ID. The error shows as follows: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in... I'm not sure what it is though.

Comment: That's just the PHP error. Did you follow the link I posted? Use a try/catch block to surround your PDO code, and add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Answer (score -1):

why you have two different variables `$SID` and `$S_ID`? And I think this line

> $query = 'SELECT * FROM student WHERE `S_ID` = :S_ID';

should be changed to

> $query = 'SELECT * FROM student WHERE 
>   S_ID = :S_ID';

Try this.

Comment: Using backticks to quote table names and column names is the proper way to quote them. It's not always necessary, but it's correct.